# Adding to a List in Android Studio, performance issues

Tags: java, android, arraylist, iterator

I made this post a few days ago: [Issues with a For-Each loop in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335092/issues-with-a-for-each-loop-in-android-studio)

I made the recommended changes of using an Iterator to remove objects from the ArrayList, and the performance issues for removing items stopped. Heres the updated update() method:

```
public void update(){
        float elapsedTime = (startTime - System.currentTimeMillis());
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        float speed = Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/10000.0f;


        Iterator<Grass> i = grasses.iterator();
        while(i.hasNext()){
            Grass g = i.next();
            g.incY(speed * elapsedTime);

            if(g.getRect().top > Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT){
                int currY = 0;
                int currX = g.getRect().left;
                i.remove();
                grasses.add(new Grass(currX, currY));

            }
        }
    }
```

The populateGrass method is the same:

```
 private void populateGrass() {
       for(int j = 0; j < ((double) Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT / grassSize) + 1; j++) {
           yStart = grassSize * (-2 + j);
           for (int i = 0; i < (double) Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH / grassSize; i++) {
                xStart = i * grassSize;
                grasses.add(new Grass(xStart, yStart));
            }
        }
    }
```

However, the issue moved to when I add new grass, I get the jittering issue. I dont think its a drop in framerate (although thats what it looks like). Im assuming a fix would be something similar to the Iterator (even though it doesnt have an "add" method).

I am using an ArrayList, would a different kind of list help?
Also my goal is to have a screen-full of seamlessly placed/moving grass. Eventually Ill change the speed with time, and add more to the game. Currently I have perfect rows, but spawning them in is jittery. And a side-effect of the "jittering" (I assume) is the grass spawning in on the wrong Y- coordinate, and they get bunched together.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the error message is the same. "ConcurrentModificationException"

Answer (score 0):

Yes, different lists offer different implementations that provide the same result just at different speeds for different functions.

For example, ArrayList, is better for looping as opposed to LinkedList. This is due to ArrayList attributes being directly accessible with an index, as opposed to the linked list which has to iterate through the nodes to get the specified node.

TL/DR:
- Linked list is better for add/remove functions.
- Array list is better for get/set

I've learned this at university otherwise would have probably needed to ask the same question.

Reference:
https://dzone.com/articles/arraylist-vs-linkedlist-vs

Comment: I was taught about LinkedLists in my CS200-level course, I just didnt really pay too much attention because we were doing theory, not coding. When it came to coding, we basically programmed our own array function and modifying it for a linkedlist and a few other kinds of lists..... I didnt know java had their own.

Comment: I changed it to a LinkedList (vs ArrayList) and I still have the same issue. I forgot to mention it in  the post but the error message is the same "ConcurrentModificationException"